# Puppet eYAML to File

Tags: puppet

I have a file that I've encrypted using `hiera-eyaml` and included in my configuration as such:

```yaml
mymodule::config_file: ENC[PKCS7,...]
```

Now I'm trying to write the contents of the decoded string into a file as such:

```
class mymodule (
  String $config_file
) {
  file { '/etc/agent_config.json':
    content => $config_file,
    mode    => '0644',
  }
}
```

I would expect the output file to be the decrypted string, but instead I'm getting the encrypted eYAML instead.

Is what I'm doing not possible to do in puppet?

Edit:

The file looks correct when running `eyaml edit`

ex:

```yaml
itglue::fireeye::fireeye_config: DEC(1)::PKCS7[{
  "serverlist": {
    "servers": [
      ...
    ]
  }
}]!
```

Edit 2:

Our `hiera.yaml` is as such:

```yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
  - eyaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hiera/hieradata
:eyaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hiera/hieradata
  :pkcs7_private_key: /var/lib/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem
  :pkcs7_public_key:  /var/lib/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem
:hierarchy:
  - secure
  - "%{::clientcert}"
  - "node_role/%{::node_role}"
  - "env/%{::environment}"
  - "node_types/%{nodetype}"
  - global
:logger: console
```

Comment: Does the hiera config contain the decryption settings?

Comment: @MattSchuchard can you be more specific as to what the decryption settings are? I have eyaml enabled as a backend and the eyaml config pointing to the correct public and private keys.

Comment: If you don't configure hiera-eyaml on the puppet server, then it cannot decrypt your secrets. An example of configuration for hiera on the puppet server can be found in the hiera-eyaml repository: https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml#hiera

Comment: I've already configured hiera-eyaml on the server. The decryption is happening, just not as the content of the file.

Comment: There should be no problem to use the decrypted value in a file content parameter. Not sure where the problem is. But I'll just underline that successfully decrypting with `eyaml edit` is not necessarily a sign that the eyaml configuration in `hiera.yaml` is correct.

Comment: Can you post your ```hiera.yaml``` file on here? I've seen a problem similar to this once before where the yaml section was before the eyaml section in the ```hiera.yaml``` file so the key was found during the yaml search rather than in the eyaml search. One of the ways to avoid this is to have a completely separate path for the secrets search as show here https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml#with-hiera-5.

Comment: @16c7x updated in question.

Comment: Your configuration appears to be for Hiera 3.  Current Puppet (all versions still supported) uses Hiera 5.  I think Hiera 5 understands the version-3 config format, but I'm not sure Hiera 5 is 100% backwards compatible.

Comment: It smells like Hiera is processing your eyaml files with the yaml backend.  Do make sure you have named them with extension `.eyaml`, not plain `.yaml`.  If you have done, then you could try flipping the order in which you declare the backends, so that eyaml comes first.  In fact, since eyaml supports both encrypted and unencrypted data in the same files, your best bet overall might be to consolidate your data into the eyaml files, and use only that backend.

Comment: If you are using Hiera 5 then you should also consider upgrading your Hiera config to the version-5 format.  This would carry the advantage that each hierarchy level has a single backend and a single data source associated, so you can be a lot more specific, and also have more control over the relative orders of encrypted and unencrypted levels.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a system with hiera version 3 to test this on so it's a complete stab in the dark, but try swapping the ordering of the backends so

```
:backends:
  - yaml
  - eyaml
```

becomes

```
:backends:
  - eyaml
  - yaml
```

If that doesn't work I'd suggest storing your secrets data in a different location so have

```
/etc/puppet/hiera/hieradata
```

for your yaml and

```
/etc/puppet/hiera/hierasecretdata
```

for the secrets, that way the yaml search will never be looking in the eyaml file where it can find a key match.